# Running a series of functions in series with ExtendScript

Tags: javascript, callback, extendscript

I need to run about 5 functions one right after the other in an ExtendScript script for Illustrator. These particular functions are currently working fine when just placing them in order:

```
functionOne();
functionTwo();
functionThree();
functionFour();
functionFive();
```

… but I know this is fragile and likely to eventually break.

I can build in callbacks, but then that feels clunky and far too confining:

```
functionOne(function() {
    functionTwo(function() {
        functionThree(...);
    });
});
```

I would love to use Promises, but that isn’t an option with ExtendScript.

Considering this, what is the recommended method be for chaining together a series of arbitrary functions?

Comment: *"I would love to use Promises, but that isn’t an option with ExtendScript."* There are several Promise libraries and polyfills. A really basic Promise implementation is about 20 lines of code...

Comment: Yeah? And would you say that’s the way to go?

Comment: Entirely up to you. It would mean your code above would be `functionOne().then(functionTwo).then(functionThree).then(functionFour).then(functionFive);`

Comment: without knowing what the functions do and how they relate it's hard to give a suggestion.